# Weebly Product description - making text aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm using weebly site builder with e-commerce store.
my entire site is aligned to the right, except 'product description' area, which I cannot find the way to edit it.
It seems weebly has programmed in the background that all text in product description will be automatically aligned to left.
when I inspect page through the browser I see:

```
.wsite-not-footer {
   text-align: left;
}
```

I cannot see this command in Weebly `HTML/CSS` editor.

My question is: where should I enter `'text-align: right'` in weebly `HTML/CSS` editor as to override the automatic alignment?

Comment: We need more details than this. Can you please share the rest of your code?

Comment: Have you tried simply _adding_ a new rule with selector `.wsite-not-footer` in the editor? If that doesn’t work, because the default styles provided by weebly are applied after your custom styles, use a selector with a higher specificity. (And should you not know what that word means in terms of CSS – research it.)

Comment: thanks for your replies. here is more code lines:
<div id="wsite-content" class="wsite-not-footer"><div id="wsite-com-product-gen" >
 <input id="wsite-com-product-view-variation-data" type="hidden" 
  <div id="wsite-com-product-divider"></div>
 <div id="wsite-com-product-info">
   <div id="wsite-com-product-info-inner"> 
     <h2 id="wsite-com-product-title">
     
     </h2>

Comment: <div id="wsite-com-product-sku" class="wsite-com-product-sku-none">
     <b class="wsite-com-product-title">SKU:</b>
     <span id="wsite-com-product-sku-value"></span>
    </div>
     <div id="wsite-com-product-short-description">
      <div class="paragraph"><strong><font size="3">     </div>
     </div>

Comment: regarding using selectors - I've tried using align texts commands in higher selectors. it did not work for me.
I think the reason is because the area in the page where I would like to align to the right is generated on the spot, so even when i use weebly editor and make changes, it always return to main page (and not to the specific product page when i see the text not aligned to the right, as i wish).
I also try to use !important command to overrule the 'text-align: left', which as mentioned, I cannot see in weebly editor (I see it only under page ispection, but to no success..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the received comments.
I finally found out a solution for my problem.
the command i was using was correct:

```
.wsite-not-footer {
   text-align: right;
}
```

it turns out that even after entering this command on weebly CSS editor, you still see the text aligned to the left.
You need to publish the site, and only after that you see the text aligned to the right as it should be.